# How can I call Lambda function from MySQL database in AWS and how can I pass a parameter to a container in ECS from the Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to call a Lambda function that creates a container with a parameter in ECS. The ECS is in my VPC and the database is in my VPC, too. I want to create a Python Lambda function and the function gets called every time new records are inserted into the database. So, when the database insertion event occurs the database triggers the lambda function.

1. How can I make the database call the Lambda function every time the database insertion event occurs in AWS?
2. How can I start a container and pass a parameter to ECS from the Lamdba function?
3. I also wonder if calling the lambda function from the database is synchronous or asynchronous.

Hope to hear some explanations about it. I have spent days on this but still cannot find the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can call the native functions lambda_sync and lambda_async when you use Aurora MySQL version 1.16 and later, or Aurora MySQL 2.06 and later.

There is a working example in the documentation for [Invoke an AWS Lambda function to send email](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.Lambda.html#AuroraMySQL.Integrating.NativeLambda)

If I were you, I would not call lambda directly from MySQL,

Whichever process(assuming lambda) writing to the Database, upon successful/failed it can take necessary actions via [AWS Lambda Destination](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-lambda-destinations/)

1.SQS Queue

2.SNS Topic

3.Event Bridge Event Bus

4.Another Lambda Function

Answer (score 2):

With pure MySQL you can't, there is no event exposed by MySQL on update. You can use Aurora MySQL and its Streams https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/06/database-activity-streams-now-available-for-aurora-with-mysql-compatability/
This flow will be asynchronous.

Comment: Can Lambda Function run asynchronously, too? I assume that it has options for both and I am just trying to make sure if it is.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Lambda is synchronous, it stops when you return it's response. But it shouldn't matter, you don't have to wait for that response and you got async code

Comment: I didn't know about the async code. Do you mean that there is an option to wait or just call the Lambda Function, return from it, and get the async code? So I can use the async code to check the result later?

Comment: Lamda is connected via network, so it's like an API call. For example if you invoke it with Node SDK you get a Promise in response. If you await for it or not is up to you